# Literature request - Classification of periodic holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, soft-question

For a seminar, I received the assignment to present the classification of periodic holomorphic/meromorphic functions. I have access to a limited amout of resources that I receive from my lecturer - However I am looking for further information. However, plugging the theme into google gave no useful results whatsoever;

Is the accessible information available somewhere that I couldnt find with google?

Are there any related keywords that I should definitely look up?

**EDIT**: I have now talked with my lecturer - I am supposed to mainly talk about periodic functions $D\to\mathbb{C}$, not elliptic functions (which means they only have 1 period). There is very little literature on the matter; Does anyone - by any chance - know a book/paper/reading script where this was handled? Mainly, I am to talk about trigonometric polinomials. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Related keywords: Elliptic functions; Weierstrass P-function. I've personally learned this subject from Lars V. Ahlfors' book *Complex Analysis* (chapter 7). Maybe you have it in your university's library?

Comment: @YoniRozenshein I will take a look. But keywords help me out equally as much, as I am not a natively english speaker; I have a hard time understanding complex matter in a different lingo. Thank you very much ;)

Comment: Weierstrass probably wrote his original works in German. Not sure you'd have an easier time reading them though :)

Comment: @YoniRozenshein I totally forgot ^.^ Yeah, Weierstrass will probably have written those in german. However, I dont know how (extremely) difficult a non-simplified research produc is. I will attempt to work myself through them nonetheless, just for the sake of it. I will receive a short introduction to the matter on friday, based on your (and Brents) help I can prepare myself for it. Again, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Complex Functions: An Algebraic and Geometric Viewpoint* by Jones and Singerman is a good start. If I remember correctly, *Kronecker's Jugendtraum and Modular Functions* by Vladut has a good section on elliptic integrals and elliptic functions.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to access these specific or similar books. Even if they do not help me, you have provided me with some helpful keywords (as I have just started gathering information). You will definitely receive the accept if there are no other questions to come ;)